# Magento 2 REST API bulk update product attributes

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.6, bulk-actions, async

I am trying to update an attribute for about a thousand products using REST API.
I'm using `async/bulk/V1/products/bySku`.

It works perfectly, but it takes forever as it saves one product at a time.

There is no method similar to "Update attributes" mass Action?

Answer (score 0):

Need to change "Update on Save" to "Update by Schedule" on Index Management